# Asp.Net MVC ActionResult with File

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, download

In Asp.Net MVC, we need to show a Html page, but also when that page shows, download a file too as the result of a form post.

Is there a kind of ActionResult that both renders HTML, but also cause the browser to download a file? Think of a page that shows "Here's your requested file" and the file starts to download.

Basically a combination of ActionResult and FileResult in one.

Comment: I will suggest to use java script. When first html renders put java script in it to call second action of fileresult. It is workaround not the answer of your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a controller example that returns a file. I added an Iframe to the view that targets the controller method. I set the hidden attribute so the iframe doesn't show anywhere in the page. Hope you can use the solution. It seems to work very smoothly.

```
    [HttpGet]
    public FileResult GetPDF()
    {
        string fileName = "test.pdf";
        string filePath = HttpContext.Server.MapPath(string.Format("~/Content/{0}", fileName));
        byte[] fileBytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(filePath);

        return File(fileBytes, System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet, fileName);
    }

Add the following code to your view.

    <iframe hidden="hidden" src="@Url.Content("~/Home/Home/GetPDF")"></iframe>
```